# Software to live stream desktop to a site

Tags: screen-capture, video-streaming

We're building a proposal to enhance customer support. The support reps would stream their desktops over the internet. To do this, we'll need software for reps to share their desktop and live stream that content to a unique link.

To summarize, we're looking for:

- capturing a desktop
- ability to stream the content live over the internet
- no need for the user to download any software

Is there any software that exists for this?

Windows Live Meeting/Communicator would be perfect, but it requires the user download that as well (unlikely). Camtasia does screen capture but doesn't provide live streaming options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously most remote desktop software can do this. I think they're even an option for this in skype. The trick is making it easy to start viewing over the web.  There are several options here:

- http://dimdim.com  I've used this a few times and it works pretty well.
- [MS Live Meeting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/live-meeting/) — probably no good, as you need client software
- [WebEx](http://www.webex.com/lpintl/us/sem/web_conferencing2.htm?CPM=KNC-sem&TrackID=1021381&semid=sWYmpndQV_4376760506)
- [FogCreek Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/)
- [GoToMeeting](https://www3.gotomeeting.com/t/gg/gotomeeting-Exact/NAPPC/g2msem3/sf/701000000005L0w;jsessionid=abcGBjtsoeDIVaAA8qoWs?Portal=www.gotomeeting.com&Target=m/g2msem3.tmpl&gclid=CJH1qMX7gqUCFYj75woddhs5QQ)
- [Adobe Connect](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobeconnect.html)